# How to implement signup for multiple types of users with python-social-auth?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I want to create 2 different signup mechanisms for 2 different user types, i.e., consumer users and vendor users. What is the simplest way to do this with python-social-auth?

To focus the discussion, let's say that there are 2 signup pages: `example.com/consumer-signup` and `example.com/vendor-signup`. This question boils down to how I can pass a value from each page to the social auth pipeline or to an authenticator like facebook so that I can retrieve that same value after authentication is complete.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely want to use [SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html#miscellaneous-settings) to configure query parameters you can pass into your `socialauth_begin` endpoint.  You can then retrieve this value in your `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` and access the request.session for this value.

Something like:

#### Your Settings

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ('user_type', )
```

#### Your Login Template

```
a href="{% url socialauth_begin '[backend]' %}?user_type=vendor">Sign-in as Vendor</a>
```

#### Your Pipeline Stage

```
def set_user_type(strategy, details, response, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    user_type = strategy.session.get('user_type')
    if user_type == 'vendor':
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for a really concise and on point answer. I had no idea that setting exists and was about to implement something that mimics its effect. Kudos!